# Why is my client run command not working?

Tags: discord.py

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\90538\PycharmProject\{ProjectName}\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
TypeError: Client.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

And my code is this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client

TOKEN = 'REDACTED'

client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
    .format(client))



client.run(TOKEN)
```

I googled for half an hour but none of the solutions worked. Help please.

Comment: Your discord token is exposed, please regenerate your token on the discord dev portal.
You should not share this token with anybody.

Comment: well its not a very important project it will only include maybe 20 lines of code so security is not my biggest concern

Comment: @Lancelot security might not be your main concern, but it is important, and it's part of being a responsible developer in the Discord ecosystem. It's fine to have it be less-secure during developement, but you should regenerate it before going live. And you should *absolutely* regenerate it now, since you've exposed it publicly. For example, people could use it to abuse the API, and it could potentially get your account banned.

Comment: The error is strange, as you clearly are providing the positional argument. My gut is saying that you're not running the file you think you're running (you're running an old copy of it), or you're not properly saving the file before running it. I've had that happen before with python. If the error is saying something about your code that is clearly false, your code might not be actually what is running.

Comment: Open `C:\Users\90538\PycharmProject\shitcumbot\main.py` direcly in the File Explorer and examine line 19.

Comment: Also, it's fine using a project name like that for a personal project (I've seen some crazy codenames), but it is not at *all* appropriate for a professional platform like StackOverflow. Censor the name (which is always good for privacy anyways), or change it. Keep in mind future employeers and coworkers may see your StackOverflow history.

Comment: @Nathan So are you saying i should rewrite the code on a different file ?

Comment: @Lancelot I'm saying that the code you posted might not be the actual code. You might have two copies of the file, and are running `python main.py` on the wrong file. Or you didn't properly save the file, and you're running `python main.py` against an old version of the code, one where `client.run()` is missing the token.

Comment: Just a hunch. Close out all your existing windows (VSCode, Notepad, or whatever IDE you're using), navigate to `"C:\Users\90538\PycharmProject\shitcumbot\main.py"` in File Explorer, and open it up. Does that code match what you posted in your question?

Comment: I couldnt open the folder containing the file and i assume it's corrupted. I'll delete it altogether and rewrite on a different project and see if that changes anything. I'll update once i do that

Comment: @Nathan It has worked, thank you !

Comment: No problem! I had a similar problem one time, it's an easy solution but really hard to think of without prior experience. Seriously though, refresh that discord token, and try to use professional project names on stack overflow in the future, k? :) Good luck with your discord bot! I just wrote my first one recently, they're pretty fun.

Comment: You haven't initialised the client, you're running methods on the class